# Joining two queries of the same table that select the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine I have this table with, projects, continents, and countries. Projects can be in a lot of countries, and in another column each country has a number that stands for its continent.

I want to make a query that returns a column for each continent filled with its countries. But at the same time I don't want it to return the projects that are not in a continent.

It would be more less joining this 3 queries:

```
SELECT PROJECTS,COUNTRIES AS `EUROPE` FROM WORLD WHERE COUNTRIES = 2;

SELECT PROJECTS,COUNTRIES AS `AFRICA` FROM WORLD WHERE COUNTRIES = 3;

SELECT PROJECTS  FROM WORLD WHERE PROJECTS NOT IN (SELECT PROJECTS FROM WORLD WHERE COUNTRIES = 1);
```

I have managed to join the last one with one of the other two, but I can not manage to join the three of them, It always return a mix of the countries in the same column instead of different ones...

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you give sample records with desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided this is the best answer I can provide:

```
SELECT PROJECT, COUNTRIES AS 'EUROPE' FROM WORLD t1
JOIN
SELECT PROJECTS,COUNTRIES AS `AFRICA` FROM WORLD t2
WHERE PROJECT NUMBER t1 = (SELECT PROJECTS FROM WORLD WHERE COUNTRIES = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
SELECT 
PROJECTS, 
CASE COUNTRIES 
     WHEN 2 THEN 'Europe'
     WHEN 3 THEN 'Africa'
     ELSE 'elsewhere'
END AS Continent
WHERE COUNTRIES IN (2, 3)
AND PROJECTS NOT IN (SELECT PROJECTS FROM WORLD WHERE COUNTRIES = 1);
```

It's not exactly one column per continent, but in my opinion the display of data has to be done on the presentation layer anyway, not on database level.